# implementing undo and redo in canvas whiteboard using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to implement undo , redo functionality in my html canvas element in angular but i am not able to do so

this is how far i have come

whenever the mouse is up i push the image of the canvas to a list and whenever i press undo i pop that list and draw the image on whole whiteBoard

here is my ts code..
please help me to do so..

```
export class CanvasComponent {
    @ViewChild('canvas') public canvas: ElementRef;

    @Input() public width = 1000;
    @Input() public height = 480;

    constructor() {}
    private cx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
    public ngAfterViewInit() {
        const canvasEl: HTMLCanvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
        this.cx = canvasEl.getContext('2d');
        canvasEl.width = this.width;
        canvasEl.height = this.height;
        this.cx.lineWidth = 5;
        this.cx.lineCap = 'round';
        this.cx.strokeStyle = '#000';
        this.captureEvents(canvasEl);
    }

    undoStack: object[] = [];
    redoStack: object[] = [];
    list: object[] = [];
    private captureEvents(canvasEl: HTMLCanvasElement) {
        // this will capture all mousedown events from the canvas element
        fromEvent(canvasEl, 'mousedown')
            .pipe(
                switchMap((e) => {
                    this.getMousePosition(canvasEl, e);
                    // after a mouse down, we'll record all mouse moves
                    return fromEvent(canvasEl, 'mousemove').pipe(
                        // we'll stop (and unsubscribe) once the user releases the mouse
                        // this will trigger a 'mouseup' event
                        takeUntil(fromEvent(canvasEl, 'mouseup')),
                        // we'll also stop (and unsubscribe) once the mouse leaves the canvas (mouseleave event)
                        takeUntil(fromEvent(canvasEl, 'mouseleave')),
                        // pairwise lets us get the previous value to draw a line from
                        // the previous point to the current point
                        pairwise()
                    );
                })
            )
            .subscribe((res: [MouseEvent, MouseEvent]) => {
                const rect = canvasEl.getBoundingClientRect();

                // previous and current position with the offset
                const prevPos = {
                    x: res[0].clientX - rect.left,
                    y: res[0].clientY - rect.top
                };

                const currentPos = {
                    x: res[1].clientX - rect.left,
                    y: res[1].clientY - rect.top
                };

                this.drawOnCanvas(prevPos, currentPos);
            });
    }

    getMousePosition(canvas, event) {
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
            console.log('stopped');
            var src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            // console.log(src);
            this.list.push(src);
        });
    }

    private drawOnCanvas(prevPos: { x: number; y: number }, currentPos: { x: number; y: number }) {
        if (!this.cx) {
            return;
        }
        this.cx.beginPath();
        if (prevPos) {
            this.cx.moveTo(prevPos.x, prevPos.y); // from
            this.cx.lineTo(currentPos.x, currentPos.y);
            this.cx.stroke();
        }
    }

    undo() {
        var src = this.list.pop();
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.setAttribute('src', src.toString());
        // console.log('src ->' + src.toString());
        this.cx.clearRect(0, 0, this.cx.canvas.width, this.cx.canvas.height);
        this.cx.drawImage(img,0,0,this.cx.canvas.width,this.cx.canvas.height,0,0,this.cx.canvas.width,this.cx.canvas.height
        );
    }
     redo(){}
     erase(){}
}
```

here is my html code

```
<canvas #canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div class="canvas-body">
  <div class="tools" >
    <button class="toolButtons" (click)="erase()">erase</button>
    <button class="toolButtons" (click)="undo()" >undo</button>
    <button class="toolButtons" (click)="redo()">redo</button>
  </div>
```

if you guys can also help me with the **erase function** that would be really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [Interacto](https://github.com/interacto/interacto-ts) library that works with Angular (`npm install interacto`).

With Interacto you can define undoable commands in TypeScript.
In your example, we have two commands: `Erase` and `AddShape`.

Here is the code of `Erase` that cleans the canvas while creating a memento:

```
export class Erase extends CommandBase implements Undoable {
  mementoCanvas: ImageData;

  constructor(private canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) {
    super();
  }

  // Create the memento for undoing the command
  protected createMemento() {
    // We copy the current state of the canvas
    const rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.mementoCanvas = this.canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height);
  }

  // Execute the command
  protected execution(): void {
    const rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height);
  }

  undo(): void {
    // We restore the former state of the canvas
    this.canvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(this.mementoCanvas, 0, 0);
  }

  redo(): void {
    this.execution();
  }

  getUndoName(): string {
    return 'Erase';
  }
}
```

Now the `AddShape` command:

```
import {CommandBase, Undoable} from 'interacto';

export class Shape {
  lines: Array<[number, number]> = [];
}

export class AddShape extends CommandBase implements Undoable {
  shape: Shape;
  mementoData: ImageData;

  constructor(private canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) {
    super();
    this.shape = new Shape();
  }

  protected createMemento() {
    const rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.mementoData = this.canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height);
  }

  protected execution(): void {
    // To use if continuous command execution:
    const cx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    cx.beginPath();
    cx.moveTo(this.shape.lines[this.shape.lines.length - 2][0], this.shape.lines[this.shape.lines.length - 2][1]);
    cx.lineTo(this.shape.lines[this.shape.lines.length - 1][0], this.shape.lines[this.shape.lines.length - 1][1]);
    cx.stroke();

    // To use if not continuous command execution:
    // this.redo();
  }


  canExecute(): boolean {
    return this.shape.lines.length > 1;
  }

  getUndoName(): string {
    return 'Add shape';
  }

  redo(): void {
    this.drawShape();
  }

  undo(): void {
    this.canvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(this.mementoData, 0, 0);
  }

  private drawShape(): void {
    let i = 0;
    const cx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    while ((i + 1) < this.shape.lines.length) {
      cx.beginPath();
      cx.moveTo(this.shape.lines[i][0], this.shape.lines[i][1]);
      cx.lineTo(this.shape.lines[i + 1][0], this.shape.lines[i + 1][1]);
      cx.stroke();
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

The Angular component now takes this form.

No more RX features. Interacto also provides predefined user interactions such as the DnD (`dndBinder`) we use here, as well as button interactions (`buttonBinder`).

Interacto natively supports undo/redo so that you just have to define how to create the predefined `Undo` and `Redo` commands.

The goal of an Interacto binding is to transform the execution of a user interaction as a (undoable) command.

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {AddShape} from '../command/add-shape';
import {buttonBinder, dndBinder, Redo, Undo} from 'interacto';
import {Erase} from '../command/erase';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-canvas',
  templateUrl: './canvas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./canvas.component.css']
})
export class CanvasComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('canvas')
  canvas: ElementRef;

  @ViewChild('erase')
  erase: ElementRef;

  @ViewChild('undo')
  undo: ElementRef;

  @ViewChild('redo')
  redo: ElementRef;

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.canvas.nativeElement.width = 200;
    this.canvas.nativeElement.height = 200;
    const cx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    cx.lineWidth = 5;
    cx.lineCap = 'round';
    cx.strokeStyle = '#000';
    this.captureEvents();
  }

  private captureEvents() {
    const rect = this.canvas.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();

    dndBinder(false)
      // The command to produce
      .toProduce(() => new AddShape(this.canvas.nativeElement))
      // What to do when the interaction starts
      .first((c, i) => {
        c.shape.lines.push([i.getSrcClientX() - rect.left, i.getSrcClientY() - rect.top]);
      })
      // What to do when the interaction updates
      .then((c, i) => {
        c.shape.lines.push([i.getTgtClientX() - rect.left, i.getTgtClientY() - rect.top]);
      })
      // On which widget the interaction operates
      .on(this.canvas.nativeElement)
      // continuous execution means that the command is executed each time the interaction updates
      .continuousExecution()
      .bind();

    buttonBinder()
      .toProduce(() => new Erase(this.canvas.nativeElement))
      .on(this.erase.nativeElement)
      .bind();

    buttonBinder()
      .toProduce(() => new Undo())
      .on(this.undo.nativeElement)
      .bind();

    buttonBinder()
      .toProduce(() => new Redo())
      .on(this.redo.nativeElement)
      .bind();
  }
}
```

I just added in the HTML file Angular ids to use the widgets in the component:

```
<canvas #canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div class="canvas-body">
  <div class="tools">
    <button #erase class="toolButtons">erase</button>
    <button #undo class="toolButtons">undo</button>
    <button #redo class="toolButtons">redo</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for undo I've made that I created an array and push in it when touchend finished

```
this.drawingSubscription = fromEvent(canvasEl, 'touchend').subscribe(res => {
  this.restore_array.push(this.cx.getImageData(0, 0, this.width, this.height))
  this.index += 1
```

})

```
undo() {
if (this.index <= 0) {
  this.restore_array = []
  this.clear()
}
else {
  this.index -= 1
  this.restore_array.pop()
  this.cx.putImageData(this.restore_array[this.index], 0, 0)
  console.log(this.index)
}
```

}

```
clear() {
this.cx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height)
this.restore_array = []
this.index=-1
```

}

```
private drawOnCanvas(prevPos: { x: number, y: number }, currentPos: { x: number, y: number }) {
if (!this.cx) { return; }
this.cx.beginPath();
if(this.bErasing == true){
  this.cx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";
  this.cx.lineWidth = 8;
}else{
  this.cx.globalCompositeOperation="source-over";
  this.cx.lineWidth = 3;
}
  this.cx.moveTo(prevPos.x, prevPos.y); // from
  this.cx.lineTo(currentPos.x, currentPos.y);
  this.cx.stroke();
  this.cx.strokeStyle = this.palette.value;
```

}

```
ngOnDestroy(){this.drawingSubscription.unsubscribe()}
```